# Is there a better way of computing the weight

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate a column based on r1/Total Weight

```
DECLARE @total float(50)
SELECT @total=sum([Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].LineTotal) from [Sales]. 
[SalesOrderDetail]

Select r.LineTotal, r.LineTotal/@total as 'weight'
from [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] r
order by LineTotal desc
```

Is there a more compact way of doing this?

Comment: It is often a mistake to write code with fewer characters. Is there actually a need to do that in this case? SQL is a declarative language: you tell it what you want and it figures out an efficient way to do it. If it doesn't, that is when you investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler with a subquery that calculates the sum:

```
SELECT 
  LineTotal, 
  LineTotal / (SELECT SUM(LineTotal) FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]) AS weight
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] 
ORDER BY LineTotal DESC
```

or with a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  s.LineTotal, 
  s.LineTotal / t.SumLineTotal AS weight
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] AS s CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(LineTotal) AS SumLineTotal 
  FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
) AS t
ORDER BY s.LineTotal DESC
```

or with a `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS  (
  SELECT SUM(LineTotal) AS SumLineTotal 
  FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
)
SELECT 
  LineTotal, 
  LineTotal / (SELECT SumLineTotal FROM cte) AS weight
FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] 
ORDER BY LineTotal DESC
```